# Spring data jpa persist multiple parents - single child

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How do I persist/update the two parents that share the same child in a single thread?

```
@Entity
class Invoice {
    @OneToMany(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "invoice")
    List<Discount> discounts;
}    

@Entity
class Coupon {
    @OneToMany(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "coupon")
    List<Discount> discounts; 
}    

@Entity
class Discount {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("invoice_id")
    Invoice invoice;    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("coupon_id")
    Coupon coupon;
}
```

This DB model makes sense, as a Discount object is created and added to an Invoice. The same discount object is created based on the existing Coupon. So Discount obj is associated with both Invoice and Coupon.

When I try to save as follows, I get error

> object references an unsaved transient instance : save the transient instance before flushing

```
createInvoice() {
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    Coupon coupon = couponRepo.query();
    Discount discount = new Discount();
    coupon.discounts.add(discount);
    discount.coupon = coupon;
    couponRepo.save(coupon);

    // save invoice
    invoice.discounts.add(discount);
    discount.invoice = invoice
    invoiceRepo.save(invoice);
}
```

I tried to created separate transactions by splitting above code into separate @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW), but it fails trying to insert the same discount object twice, with duplicate primary key error.

Should I use native queries instead?

Comment: Why do you set new `Discount` object to `coupon` entitiy?

Comment: Discount is the realization of a coupon. @Geeth Let's ignore the Discount, Coupon for a moment. In the DB, I can create a db model with a single table that can have multiple fk references to multiple tables. This is the same as multiple ManyToOne relations in that Entity in Hibernate. Is it not possible for ORM to map this db model?

Comment: You can do anything in JPA/ORM and there is nothing wrong with your model - it is just your understanding and expectations that might be in error. You are getting a duplicate insert because you have duplicated things without realizing it. In this case, you call save on coupon, which references a new discount. If you check what is happening, I suspect Spring is calling persist on your object graph, but is within its own EM context which it commits/closes. You then call save on invoice which sees the same discount data, and calls persist on it - so you've saved it twice as a new object.

Comment: Set the discount->Coupon and discount->Invoice relation to cascade persist, create your discount/coupon/invoice objects as you have now, but only call save on the discount instance when everything is set. This will persist discount, invoice and coupon. This could work as is if there was only a single transactional context around the createInvoice that was used by the two save repository calls you make, and only if it is using em.persist under the covers. You should use the discount instance returned from first save call, as this might be a different instance when spring uses merge.

Comment: @Chris thanks. However, having cascade persist on both parents (Invoice/Coupon) causes issues. Removing cascade on one of the parents and persisting changes through one of the parent via cascade and after this updating the child directly with the other parent link works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved as follows:

Removed cascade (should be removed in entirety) on one of the parents(say Invoice).

```
@Entity
class Invoice {
    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "invoice")
    List<Discount> discounts;
}
```

Next, create a new child (discount), add it to the parent with the cascade, and save the parent. Once the child is saved, create and save the other new parent. Then update the child by associating with the other parent and saving the child directly.

```
@Transactional
createInvoice() {
    // get parents
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    Coupon coupon = couponRepo.query();
 
    // create child and add to parent
    Discount discount = new Discount();
    coupon.discounts.add(discount);
    discount.coupon = coupon;
   
    // save parent with cascade
    couponRepo.saveAndFlush(coupon);

    // save invoice
    invoiceRepo.save(invoice);

    // update child add other parent
    discount.invoice = invoice
    discountRepo.saveAndFlush(discount);
}
```

Comment: This works for you because coupon is already managed by the underlying EntityManager - the instance from couponRepo.query() is used in your other relationships.You must have added cascade options from discount->invoice or invoice would not be saved. So you don't really need to call saveAndFlush(coupon) or even saveAndFlush(discount); coupon is managed, so JPA will pick up that it now reverences a new discount which references a new invoice for you when the transaction commits.

Comment: I don't want changes to cascade from discount to invoice, as discount can be removed but not invoice and this may result in a recursive loop. So when discount was being saved, JPA threw error 'invoice is a transient object, First save invoice before discount'. But you may be right. I need to try your approach as well.